# Docker behind proxy that changes ssl certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, rhel, docker

I am trying to run the following docker command:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

But I get the error:

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu' (tag: latest) locally

Pulling repository ubuntu
2013/11/28 14:00:24 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/images/ubuntu/ancestry: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I know that our company replaces the SSL Certificate on the fly for https requests.

I tried to trust our company's CA certificate by putting it in:

```
 /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

and

```
/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
```

But it is still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To configure docker to work with a proxy system you first need to add the HTTPS_PROXY / HTTP_PROXY environment variable to the docker sysconfig file. However depending on if you use init.d or the services tool you need to add the "export" statement. As a workaround you can simply add both variants in the sysconfig file of docker:

```
/etc/sysconfig/docker

HTTPS_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
HTTP_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
export HTTP_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://<user>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"
```

To get docker working with ssl intercepting proxies you have to add the proxy root certificate to the systems trust store.

For CentOS copy the file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ and update the ca trust store. Restart the docker service afterwards.
If your proxy uses NTLM authentication - it's necessary to use intermediate proxies like cntlm.
[This blog post explains it in detail](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/11/using-docker-with-a-proxy.html)

Answer (score 20):

@jpetazzo's answer is overall correct, however there is a nicer way to do the same thing (without manually editing a ca-bundle file):

- on CentOS:

  ```
  sudo cp yourcert.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
  sudo update-ca-trust extract
  sudo service docker restart
  ```
- on Debian:

  ```
  sudo cp yourcert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
  sudo update-ca-certificates
  sudo service docker restart
  ```

Note that restarting docker daemon is necessary!

Answer (score 14):

According to http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/x509/root_unix.go, you should append your certificate to one of the following:

- /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
- /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
- /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
- /etc/ssl/cert.pem
- /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt

Find the one that exists on your system, and append your certificate to it.

(And be ready to do it again when you upgrade the package containing that file...)

I hope there is a better method, but this is the only one I found so far :-)

Comment: I put the certificate in the first file and now i got rid of this error, but I got a new one.

Comment: I also had to restart the Docker daemon by `sudo service docker restart`. Thanks!