# Unable to run pull Docker Image behind proxy using Toolbox on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am not able to pull docker images behind corp proxy. I get the error -

```
docker pull owasp/zap2docker-stable
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.102:2376/v1.37/info: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.102 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs). 
Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.102:2376/v1.37/images/create?fromImage=owasp%2Fzap2docker-stable&tag=latest: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.102 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

What am I doing wrong? (I cannot use Hyper-V and Docker for Windows)

192.168.99.102 is the IP address of my Docker Instance `default`

Update - ran `export NO_PROXY=192.168.99.102` . Then ran `docker pull <image>`
Got error - `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: As per the error docker has access to the public registry but failed because of the ssl error. You can update daemon.json to ignore the ssl error for that repo. It is not a good practice but worth a try because at times corporate proxies are autheticated via AD login i.e creds need to be supplied

Answer (score 0):

If that endpoint is not reachable its some thing to do with your network.

You can also download image in another pc (without corp proxy) and load it into your pc

To save a downloaded image (assuming pulled already using docker pull):

```
docker save -o <output location>.docker <image name>:<tag, e.g. latest or specific version>
```

Then once copied to the target container host execute

```
docker load -i <imagename>.docker
```

Check it is shown in list (`docker images`).

Comment: More curious as to how to solve this error. I have to work on a lot of images from Online

Comment: Here is the official link https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: Do I run them in my VBox Instance or the Docker Toolbox command line?

Comment: In command line. You need to set your system Environment variable. The link has steps for linux pc, you need to set the same in windows env - command would vary

Comment: I set that proxy a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a previous company where the corporate proxy was doing TLS interception. (see [related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49509/does-a-tls-interception-proxy-present-the-users-browser-with-the-end-servers-c))

The solution was to add the proxy's certificate to the list of trusted certificates of the virtual machine created by docker toolbox. You will find more details [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267339/docker-behind-proxy-that-changes-ssl-certificate)